# Rails advance month to february sometimes fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am making a payments arrangement, for an order, where a client can choose the day of the month to pay. And can also change it afterwards. For this I used the advance method for date, and it works correctly when creating, but fails when updating. Here is my code:

Creating, if day is 31, it properly changes to last day of month if the month doesn't have a day 31.

```
months = params[:payment][:months].to_i
pay_day = params[:payment][:pay_day].to_i

today = Date.today
first_date = today.change(months: 1).change(day: pay_day)   
months_between = (today.year * 12 + today.month) - (first_date.year * 12 + first_date.month)

quota = (invoice_total)/months
payment_number = 1

months.times do |i|
    payment = Payment.new(invoice: current_invoice, payment_type: PaymentType.find(params[:payment][:payment_type_id]), payment_number: payment_number, value: quota, max_payment_date: first_date.advance(months: +(months_between+i+1)))
    payment.save
    payment_number = payment_number + 1
end
```

Update code, it fails in, for example, February with "invalid date", but updates january correctly.

```
pay_day = params[:payment][:pay_day].to_i

@invoice.payments.each do |payment|
    if payment.actual_payment_date.nil?

        reference_month = payment.max_payment_date.change(months: 1).change(day: pay_day)
        months_between = (payment.max_payment_date.year * 12 + payment.max_payment_date.month) - (reference_month.year * 12 + reference_month.month)

        payment.update_attributes(max_payment_date: reference_month.advance(months: +(months_between)))
        payment.save
    end
end
```

It is basically the same code, does anyone know why in the first part it works correctly, but not the second part?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSupport to the rescue:

```
def correct_day(day, date = Date.today)
  end_of_month = date.end_of_month.day
  day < end_of_month ? day : end_of_month
end
```

Lets test it with [timecop:

```
Timecop.freeze(Date.new(2000, 02)) do
  correct_day(32) # => 29 - 2000 was a leap year.
  correct_day(15) # => 15
end

Timecop.freeze(Date.new(2015, 10, 11)) do
  correct_day(32) # => 31
  correct_day(15) # => 15
end
```

This is how you would implement it in a model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments

  # Creates a payment for each month
  # @param [Integer] months 
  # @param [Ingeger] preferred_day - defaults to the last day of the month
  def split_payments(months = 12, preferred_day = 31)
    (1..months).map do |i|
      payments.create(
          pay_day: calculate_payment_date(created_at + i.months, preferred_day),
          payment_number: i
          # ... More attributes
      )
    end
  end

  def change_payment_date(preferred_day)
    payments.sort_by(:payment_number).map do |payment|
      date = created_at + payment.payment_number.months
      payment.update_attributes(
        pay_day: calculate_payment_date(date, preferred_day) 
      )
    end
  end

  private

    def calculate_payment_date(date, preferred_day)
      end_of_month = date.end_of_month
      pref = date.beginning_of_month + (preferred_day - 1).days
      pref < end_of_month ? pref : end_of_month
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked and I think it is a better more safe approach. I still don't understand why my previous code worked in one place and not in another, but your workaround is much better.

Comment: One slight error should have been `payment.update_attributes` since the signature for `update_attribute`is different.